# There's an unnecessary white space at the bottom of my webpage, where is it coming from and how can I get rid of it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, whitespace, fadein

I just recently added a fadein onload function to the site but now there's a white space at the bottom. I feel like it has to do with when the div loads in it's automatically displayed as block. I'm not sure how to fix this.

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Me</title>
<script src="../js/modernizr.custom.85628.js"></script>
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="../css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="icon" type="text/css" href="../images/favicon.png" />
<script src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/myscript.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<section class="main_front">
<nav id="nav_container">

<div class="logo"><img src="../images/logo.png" height="65px" /></div><!--end of logo-->
<ul class="right_links">
<li class="nav_li"><a href="#">Goals</a></li>
<li class="nav_li"><a href="#">School Site</li></a>
<li class="nav_li"><a href="#">Web Design</li></a>
<li class="nav_li"><a href="#">Summer</li></a>
<li class="nav_li"><a href="#">Schedule</li></a>
</ul><!--end of right_links-->

</nav><!--end of nav_container-->
<div class="all_home">

<div class="home">
<div class="home_content">
Total Recall
</div><!--end of home_content-->

<div class="home_content2">
<p>A webpage about me.</p>
</div><!--end of home_content2-->
</div><!--end of home-->

<div class="home_imgs">
<div class="tech_cluster">
<img src="../images/techcluster.png" />
</div><!--end of tech_cluster-->
</div><!--end of home_imgs-->

</div><!--end of all_home-->
</section><!--end of main_front-->



<section class="footer">
<div class="contact">
<div class="phonenumber">
<img src="../images/23194.png" width="20" height="20" /> 239-XXX-XXXX
</div><!--end of phonenumber-->
<div class="email">
<img src="../images/icon-ios7-email-outline-128.png" width="23" height="23" class="mail_icon"/>
<a href="mailto:adesign@email.com">adesign@email.com</a>
</div><!--end of email-->
</div><!--end of contact-->
</section><!--end of footer-->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html {
    cursor:default; 
}

body {
    margin:0;
    margin:none;    
}

.logo {
    float:left;
    margin-top:5px; 
}

.main_front {
    width:100%;
    height:90vh;
    background-color:#A9D2F1;   
}

/* .nav_links {
    width:1600px;
    height:100px;
    margin:auto;
    color:white;    
} */

.nav_li {
    float:right;
    margin-right:20px;
}




#nav_container {
    width:100%;
    height:79px;    
    /*background-color:#82B5E8;*/
    background-image:url(../images/nav_container_bg.png);
}

.right_links {
    width:70%;
    float:right;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
}

.right_links a {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    font-size:17px;
    margin-top:0px;
    height:30px;
    padding-top:15px;
    font-family:Montserrat, "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}

.right_links li {
    width:130px;
    height:40px;    
    line-height:10px;
    text-align:center;  
    border-radius:15px;
    transition:all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition:all 0.5s;
}

.right_links li a {
    display:block;
    width:130px;
    height:40px;
}



.right_links li:hover {
    background-color:rgba(22,96,131,0.5);

}   

.phonenumber {
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;  
    margin-right:25px;
}

.phonenumber img {
    margin-top:4px; 
}

.contact {
    width:500px;
    height:9vh;
    background-color:#80b1e1;   
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
}

.email {
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.mail_icon {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-25px;
    margin-top:1px;
}

.email a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition:0.3s;    
}

.email a:hover {
    color:#313131;
}   

.footer {
    width:100%;
    height:10vh;
    background-color:#8FC6ED;
}   

.all_home {
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:700px;
    margin:auto;
}

.home_content {
    width:175px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#6886CC;
    border-radius:15px;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:30px;
    padding:15px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    padding-left:25px;
    padding-right:25px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:32px;
    text-align:center;
}

.home_content2 {
    width:275px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#6886CC;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:22px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:25px;
    line-height:40px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}

.home_imgs {
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
}

.tech_cluster {
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;  
    margin-left:8px;
    margin-top:-10px;
}

/* .iphone {    
    margin-top:20px;
    float:left; 
    margin-left:511px;
}

.computer {
    margin-top:21px;
    margin-left:61px;
    float:left;
}

.ipad {
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:56px;
    float:left;
} */
```

JavaScript/jQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.all_home').fadeIn(600);
});
```

Comment: because you are using `height:700px;` on class `all_home`..remove it and you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make replace in you css as given below.

```
*.footer {
    background-color: #8FC6ED;
    height: 22vh;
    width: 100%;
}*
```